# Trying to capture desktop image using getUserMedia and canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am making an chrome extension through which I can get a screenshot of user's desktop. I am using `chrome.desktopCapture` API to get stream of selected window.
I am creating video element dynamically. Once its source it set, I invoked the `play()` method. Then I created a canvas element and used it to draw an image of video. I am also able to get the dataURL using `canvas.toDataURL()` but when i open this url I see no image. And also this URL value remains same even during new capture.

Manifest.json -

```
{
  "name": "Desktop Capture Example",
  "description": "Show desktop media picker UI",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
     "persistent": false,
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
    "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Take a screen shot of Desktop!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "desktopCapture"
  ]
}
```

Background.js -

```
var pending_request_id = null;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {

   pending_request_id = chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["screen", "window"],onAccessApproved);

});

function gotStream(stream) {
  console.log("Received local stream");
  var video = document.createElement('video');
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  video.play();
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
   var url = canvas.toDataURL();
  console.log(url);
  //localstream = stream;
  //stream.onended = function() { console.log("Ended"); };
}

function getUserMediaError() {
  console.log("getUserMedia() failed.");
}

function onAccessApproved(id) {
  if (!id) {
    console.log("Access rejected.");
    return;
  }
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
      audio:false,
      video: { mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
                            chromeMediaSourceId: id } }
  }, gotStream, getUserMediaError);
}
```

Comment: Could you show the value of toDataURL()? also your gotStream function should fire only once, you may want to make the video element into a global variable and then call a snapshot function which will draw it to a canvas before getting the dataURL

Comment: Value of toDataURL() : data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACWCAYAAABkW7XSAAAEYklEQVR4Xu3UAQkAAAwCwdm/9HI83BLIOdw5AgQIRAQWySkmAQIEzmB5AgIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg+UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARs... this string is repeated 9 times more seperated by "/"

Comment: @Kaiido gotStream function is fired only once. And making video element global didn't help.

Comment: add a setTimeout before taking the snapshot, you'll see what I mean. It's actually that you take it before it's even drawn onto the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the video actually loads the stream : rewrite your gotStream like so :

```
function gotStream(stream) {
  console.log("Received local stream");
  var video = document.createElement('video');
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function(){
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = this.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = this.videoHeight;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      var url = canvas.toDataURL();
      console.log(url);
      // will open the captured image in a new tab
      window.open(url);
    },false);
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  video.play();
  }
```

Also, in order to get a better quality image, you have to set the mandatory maxHeight and maxWidth of the getUserMedia() call :

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
      audio:false,
      video: { mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
                            chromeMediaSourceId: id,
                            maxWidth: 4000,
                            maxHeight: 4000} }
  }, gotStream, getUserMediaError);
```

Comment: Thanks It worked But image size is always 300 * 150. How to fix this?

Comment: set the canvas' `height` and `width` properties before you draw on it

Comment: It helped but generated image is of low quality.

Comment: yes it will stretch to 640x480 as you wrote in the OP. If you want full size, then use `video.videoWidth` and `video.videoHeight` and you should set it in the mandatory object

Comment: Thanks! Setting the canvas width and height same as that video worked.

Comment: The extension works perfectly but if I dont use window.open(), the selected window comes to focus. How to avoid this?

Comment: I don't know, might worth a new question, but it seems like legit it needs to set this selected window in front