# Desktop capture - Does not show all windows during sharing contents of Desktop

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Here is the link to my extension code:

[Trying to capture desktop image using getUserMedia and canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312293/trying-to-capture-desktop-image-using-getusermedia-and-canvas)

The problem is that when I use :

```
 chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["screen", "window"],onAccessApproved);
```

It asks me to share contents of my screen. But it doesn't show all windows that are active on my desktop.

Example: Sometimes my skype is minimised and if click the extension icon it opens a sharing panel and asks me to share desktop contents but skype window is not shown in this panel. If I click on skype from my task bar, the sharing panel shows skype. Reason for this behaviour?

How to show all my windows on sharing screen?

Comment: So what you're saying is, it's not allowing you to select minimized windows?

Comment: Not always. Sometimes minimized windows are shown and sometimes not

Comment: But whenever you have this problem, the target window is minimized and it's Skype?

Comment: It happens with other windows as well. Suppose, If sharing panel is opened and skype is there, if i minimize skype it is removed from sharnig panel too. Again opening this panel skype is not shown unless I bring skype to focus

Comment: Can you give an example when a minimized window will be shown? I tested it, and as far as I can tell minimized windows do not show up.

Comment: When sharing panel is opened, open minimized window,  then it can be seen in panel, but as soon as you minimize it , it will be removed from panel

Answer (score 0):

Well, the behavior is consistent: on Windows, minimized windows are not shown as eligible capture targets. There is no way around it.

This limitation is not documented, which is regrettable; it may also be OS-specific.

---

Specifically, [Windows implementation](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/window_capturer_win.cc) contains the following comment:

```
// Skip windows that are invisible, minimized, have no title, or are owned,
// unless they have the app window style set.
```

Interestingly, this seems more like a Mac limitation than a Windows one:

```
// Return a 1x1 black frame if the window is minimized, to match the behavior
// on Mac.
```

Comment: I tried it again. You are right. Any windows behing chrome will be captured not minimized ones. Should I report it to google?

Comment: Like I said, I suppose this is a limitation that Google can't work around (same reason we can't have reasonable 3D VR desktop apps yet on Win 8)